# Why StrongSwan allows to have same IP on both sides of tunnel?

Tags: ipsec, strongswan

By mistake, I configured StrongSwan in such manner:

---

left=10.10.10.10
right=10.10.10.10

---

I saved file, reloaded IPSec confit and restarted StrongSwan daemon.
Normally, with such configuration,  I would expect some sort of errors in *systemctl* but StrongSwan was active and on *tcpdump* I could see how my IF is trying to establish IPSec connection with itself.
Why StrongSwan is not validating errors in users config or why it is treating my config as valid?

Comment: What answer do you want from the community? This looks like it should be a [bug report](https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues) instead.

Comment: @MichaelHampton if no one answers I will open new bug. But I think that it is a good practice to ask, then shoot :)